# Issues with working with the ASP:RegularExpressionValidator control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I wrote some code a while back to check if the input string conforms to a given regular expression in C# using ASP.NET. The control in question here is the `ASP:RegularExpressionValidator` control. The thing is, I've got a regular expression against which I check the validity of the input string, and an error message pops if the input string is invalid. 
This is my C# code what i tried:

```
protected void Validate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Match expression = Regex.Match(getString.Text, validator.ValidationExpression);
            bool matchSuccess = expression.Success;
            if (matchSuccess)
                match.Text = "Match success";
            else
                match.Text = "Match fail";
        }
```

And this here is the code to my ASP web form:

```
<div style="font-family:'Segoe UI'">
        <asp:TextBox ID="getString" runat="server" Width="300"/>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validator" runat="server" ValidationExpression="ADMIN.[A-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,10}" ControlToValidate="getString" ErrorMessage="does not conform to expression" />
        <asp:Button ID="Validate" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClick="Validate_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="match" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

Now the thing is, when I click on the 'Validate' button, it should show that the string either conforms to the regex and that the match is successful or that the string does not conform to the regex and the match has failed.

But my page shows that that the match is successful, while simultaneously showing the error message for the `ASP:RegularExpressionValidator` control.

How do I work around this issue ?

Comment: i think issue is with your `Regex`. can you specify requirement for Regular Expression

Comment: A RegEx is required in this case to check if an entered access ID is valid or not.
If (this input conforms to the RegEx)
    AddInputToDatabase();
else
   //print something here;

Comment: can you specify which are your valid string and which are not using this Regular Expression.

Comment: ADMIN.XYZ1993 would seem a valid string.
ADMI.XYZ.1993 is an invalid one.

Comment: i think ADMIN.XYZ1993 is not valid. You can check on http://www.regexr.com/ it shows `2 Matches` that means it will be considered as two strings(which are invalid)

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the code in the `Validate_Click` function (don't forget to remove the `OnClick` event handler from the button). The `RegularExpressionValidator` will handle the textbox validation automatically with no additional code requirements.

Comment: I checked this expression against a few strings at [link] http://www.regexr.com. All the strings that I entered there matched the regEx. But on the ASP web page, the RegularExpressionValidator would display it's ErrorMessage.

Comment: Double check your regex syntax. I was able to find a string that fit, but im guessing that your regex does not match your expected input. In particular, check the meaning of a ".".

Comment: That "." is part of the regex. 
ADMIN.XYZ1993 would be a valid string.

Comment: Then you should escape it by placing a backslash before it: "\.". "." by itself matches any character in a regular expression.